# How to remove old value some matrix in new matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I want to remove the filled value in the old matrix to my new matrix. What syntax or code in python to do that?

Here's the matrix from the old matrix to the final matrix I want to be like.
How to do that in python? Is there any syntax or maybe some code to remove the old value in new the final matrix?

[here's the final result I want to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC58P.png)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv

read = pd.read_csv('rating_trainingreg.csv')

ratings_df = pd.pivot_table(raw_dataset_df, index='User_ID',
                        columns='Training_ID',
                        aggfunc=np.max)

predicted_ratings_df = pd.DataFrame(index=ratings_df.index,
                                columns=ratings_df.columns,
                                data=predicted_ratings)

reviewed_training_df = reviewed_training_df.join(training_df, 
on='Training_ID')
already_reviewed = reviewed_training_df['Training_ID']
newMatrix = predicted_ratings_df.index,isin(already_reviewed) == False

newMatrix



OLD matirx:

                               Rating   
TrainingID|   1001  |  1002  |  1003  | 1004 |
UserID    |         |        |        |   2  |
1         |    2    |        |        |   3  |
2         |         |    3   |        |      |
3         |    2    |        |        |      |
4         |         |        |        |      |

After some calculation:
                               Rating   
TrainingID|   1001   |  1002   |  1003  | 1004 |
UserID    |     1    |    2    |   2    |   2  |
1         |     2    |    3    |   3    |   3  |
2         |     3    |    3    |   4    |   2  |
3         |     2    |    1    |   4    |   2  |
4         |     4    |    1    |   5    |   2  |

Final matrix that I want:

                               Rating   
TrainingID|   1001  |  1002   |  1003  | 1004 |
UserID    |     1   |    2    |   2    |      |
1         |         |    3    |   3    |      |
2         |     3   |         |   4    |   2  |
3         |         |    1    |   4    |   2  |
4         |     4   |    1    |   5    |   2  |
```

Comment: Please do not show code (nor matrices) as images

Comment: And please show what you've tried so far as well.

Comment: Please replace the images with text

Comment: Here what I've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```py
# manual way
newMatrix[2005][1001] = None
newMatrix[2002][1002] = None
newMatrix[2003][1004] = None
newMatrix[2005][1005] = None
newMatrix[2007][1007] = None
```

Now, the right way, if you have a very long matrix:

```py
# iterate the old matrix to set None in the new matrix where appropriate
for i, j in oldMatrix.iterrows():
    if oldMatrix[i][j]:
        newMatrix[i][j] = None
```

Comment: [Answer edited] Iterate the old array to edit the cells. If the old cell is not falsy, then set the new cell to None.

Comment: If the after calculation matrix are different from the old matrix. How I remove in the final matrix?